# Can I use Optaplanner to locally optimize the solution I input without changing most of the sequence?

Tags: java, optaplanner

At present, I have established my business model by referring to the tsp problem. The part I input is an ordered data set (an initial solution can be regarded as a route of tsp). This initial solution is compiled by the production scheduling system, so most of the routes are reasonable, and there may be a few unreasonable places. According to the configured constraint rules, I can find the violation of the solution constraint (that is, unreasonable place) through ScoreManager.
My question is, can I continue to use solver for local optimization? The ideal situation is to keep most of the sequence of the original plan, and only fine-tune the unreasonable part of the plan to satisfy all constraints.
ps:My hard constraints are some production process constraints, for example, the width difference between adjacent slabs does not exceed xxx
The soft constraint is that the smaller the sum of the difference between adjacent slabs, the better.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that, in order to satisfy all constraints, only the "unreasonable" part of the plan will have to change. The solver may or may not still need to make significant changes.

That said, consider implementing [non-disruptive replanning](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/repeated-planning/repeated-planning.html#nonvolatileReplanning). If you penalize the number of changes between the original plan and the new one, you should be able to find a reasonable balance.